# How do you combine an image and meta data as input in machine learning?

Tags: machine-learning, mathematical-statistics, tensorflow, keras, artificial-intelligence

Well my question is really about text, but image is easier to understand.

Let’s say I have some images and some meta data about the images and I want to train a model with the metadata and the image combined, how would I do it?

Would I combine the meta data and pixels as one array and pass that as input? Would my model learn properly this way?

Edit: Ok well it’s not really about images but about text, i thought it would be simpler but I guess I just over complicated it.

Anyway, I’m building a reddit post to upvotes predictor based on title, desc and post age and I’m just wondering how I would design that model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a model that takes 2 inputs. Here's an example of how this works:

1. The first input takes the image and turns it into a feature vector, perhaps by using a series of convolutional layers.
2. The second input takes the metadata and turns it into a feature vector, perhaps using a series of fully-connected layers.
3. Concatenate both feature vectors.
4. Use some number of fully-connected layers to yield a predicted output.

Comments suggest this is easy to do in Keras. (I mostly use pytorch.)

Comment: After reading a bit, this is actually pretty easy with Keras using it's "functional" properties and it's "Model" class, thank you for your reply!

Comment: Perfect. I haven't used Keras in a few years so my recollections may be outdated.